# Combine 3 tables to show all rows

Tags: mysql, join, union

I'm trying to write a MySql query that will join all 3 tables as described below...

My tables:

```
clients
| client_id | first_name | award_id | country_id |
| 1         | jon        | 3        | 2          |
| 2         | gary       | 5        | 4          |
| 3         | ted        | 1        | 2          |
| 4         | liz        | 3        | 5          |
| 5         | bill       | 1        | 5          |

awards
| award_id | award_name |
| 1        | award_1    |
| 2        | award_2    |
| 3        | award_3    |
| 4        | award_4    |
| 5        | award_5    |
| 6        | award_6    |

countries
| country_id | country_name |
| 1          | England      |
| 2          | Ireland      |
| 3          | USA          |
| 4          | France       |
| 5          | Finland      |
| 6          | Holland      |
| 7          | Germany      |
| 8          | Spain        |
```

My desired output:

```
query_results
| client_id | first_name | award_id | country_id | award_id | award_name | country_id | country_name |
| 1         | jon        | 3        | 2          | 3        | award_3    | 2          | Ireland      |
| 2         | gary       | 5        | 4          | 5        | award_5    | 4          | France       |
| 3         | ted        | 1        | 2          | 1        | award_1    | 2          | Ireland      |
| 4         | liz        | 3        | 5          | 3        | award_3    | 5          | Finland      |
| 5         | bill       | 1        | 5          | 1        | award_1    | 5          | Finland      |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | 2        | award_2    | null       | null         |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | 4        | award_4    | null       | null         |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | 6        | award_6    | null       | null         |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | null     | null       | 1          | England      |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | null     | null       | 3          | USA          |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | null     | null       | 6          | Holland      |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | null     | null       | 7          | Germany      |
| null      | null       | null     | null       | null     | null       | 8          | Spain        |
```

I have been trying to combine these with the following query...

```
SELECT * FROM clients
LEFT JOIN countries ON clients.award_id = awards.award_id 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM clients
RIGHT JOIN awards ON clients.award_id = awards.award_id 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM clients
LEFT JOIN countries ON clients.country_id = countries.countries_id 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM clients
RIGHT JOIN countries ON clients.country_id = countries.countries_id
```

This query fails with an error code 1222. However the first UNION works but fails at the third.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: UNION requires the same number of columns (they could be dummy columns) in every select

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Union of multiple queries has same number of columns returns from each query. You can just do that by adding `null` values of columns that are not present in each query.

```
SELECT * 
FROM clients c
LEFT JOIN awards a ON c.award_id = a.award_id
LEFT JOIN countries cs ON c.country_id = cs.country_id

UNION ALL

SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, a1.award_id, a1.award_name, NULL, null
FROM awards a1

UNION ALL 

SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, c1.country_id, c1.country_name
FROM countries c1
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use UNION here,since you need both matching and non-matching data in all 3 tables use FULL OUTER JOIN first on 2 tables and use the result of that query to join with third table again with FULL OUTER JOIN since Desired Output has matching+non-matching rows.
**CODE:**

```
SELECT pop.client_id, 
       pop.first_name, 
       pop.award_id, 
       pop.country_id, 
       c.award_id, 
       c.award_name, 
       pop.countryid, 
       pop.countryname 
FROM   (SELECT a.client_id, 
               a.first_name, 
               a.award_id, 
               a.country_id, 
               b.country_id   AS countryid, 
               b.country_name AS countryname 
        FROM   clients a 
               FULL OUTER JOIN countries b 
                            ON a.country_id = b.country_id) pop 
       FULL OUTER JOIN awards c 
                    ON c.award_id = pop.award_id 
ORDER  BY client_id, 
          award_name nulls last;
```

Comment: Do we have `Full outer join ` in MySQL.

Comment: Ahh I missed the MySQL part in question.

Comment: We don't have Full Outer Join in MySQL but it can be created by doing UNION ALL/ UNION on Left join and Right Join.